# Set size of the loaded image in AS3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm loading images from xml file. I want the images to have standard width when they are displayed.

Here are the snippets of the code that do the image processing:

```
var allThumbs:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(allThumbs);

allThumbs.width = 200;
allThumbs.height = 200;

galleryPane.source = allThumbs;
```

and here's the one that loades the images:

```
function loadTheThumbs() {

    var c:Number = 0;

    while(c < totalCats) {

    var thumbLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var thumbRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(catImgList[c]);
    thumbLoader.load(thumbRequest);
    thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, whenThumbLoaded);

        function whenThumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
            allThumbs.addChild(thumbLoader);
        }
    c++;
    }


}
```

Everything worked cool before I inserted

```
allThumbs.width = 200;
allThumbs.height = 200;
```

this lines, where I wanted to resize the images before they show up in the ScrollPane.

I saw other threads here, but didn't help...

So maybe any ideas how should I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the problems you had when you added those lines?

Comment: @Mansuro nothing is being displayed

Comment: For god sakes do not nest functions inside of functions. And surely do not nest a function inside a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   function whenThumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
        allThumbs.addChild(thumbLoader);
    }
```

you might want to set up the position of the images and the scale here

```
   function whenThumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
        thumbloader.x = c * 220;
        thumbloader.y = 0;
        thumbloader.width = 200;
        thumbloader.height = 200;
        allThumbs.addChild(thumbLoader);
    }
```